# Contextual link missing for particular content type

Tags: navigation

I seem to be missing the contextual link (cog) for editing nodes of a particular content type. The contextual links are rendering just fine across a multitude of other content types.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Have you tried to dump the vars in theme_preprocess_page and see if it's there? Last time i had a css class hiding the contextual links for a node-type.

Comment: @FilipePereira I'll admit, I'm not certain how to do that

Comment: Does anyone have any other suggestions?